# Insert newline into source after appendChild()

Tags: javascript, html, newline, appendchild

I'm creating a div using

```
document.getElementById("vidContainer").appendChild(divNode);
```

This creates a `div` inside `vidContainer` and because it's in a loop it creates several of these `<div>`s. Everything displays on the page the way I want it to, perfectly.

My problem is that I want my source to look nice, too. I can insert `\n` wherever I want in the `innerHTML` and that breaks things up nicely, but the closing `div` tag and opening `div` tag of the new one run together on the same line.

```
</div><div class="jkh">
```

I'm looking for a way to insert a `\n` between the `</div>` and the `<div class="jkh">`

Is there any way to have the `appendChild()` do this or is there any other way to insert that `\n` immediately after the end of one and beginning of another div?

Comment: New line inside source between tags doesn't affect anything. From what I know it's visible only inside `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You won't be able to see the source anyway. (Neither in `view-source:` nor the Developer Tools)

Comment: I can see it when I highlight the section on the page in FF and then right-click->view source.

Comment: @carlos that's all I'm trying to do... make the source look nice.

Comment: @JasonMayoff - The default console in Firefox sucks... Try Firebug or Developer Tools in Webkit browsers instead.

Comment: @JasonMayoff I think you might have a much better time with Inspect Element

Comment: @JasonMayoff - And I thought you were [developing websites for 2 decades](http://jasonmayoff.com/web/)?

Comment: @derek Have been off and on. I've managed to avoid manually programming JS for this long, though. I am pretty proficient at PHP. Not that's here or there.

Comment: I guess the consensus is, it doesn't matter and might even slow things down, so don't do it. So, I won't.

Comment: @JasonMayoff - Yup. Don't do it except it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Consoles in browsers usually will insert new lines automatically.

[image]

> **Chrome**　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　**Firefox (with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/))**

However, if you really want to add new lines manually, you will have to do this, which is not recommended:

```
var nodes = "<div>abc</div>\n\
<div>def</div>";

document.body.innerHTML = nodes;

//-or-

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/yL2c6/

---

**Why you shouldn't add new lines manually**

- It makes your script runs slower
- Not necessary
- Might mess up DOM